# Saving the previous state in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

In one of my functions "pressBtn1" I changed the previous state of a component displaying a number:

```
pressBtn1=(e)=> {       
   this.setState(function(prevState){
       return(
       {number: prevState.number+"1"});
       });
}
```

In function pressBtn2 I need to save the prevState in the global variable "buffer" for reusing it in other functions. I don't know how to do it. Can somebody help me?

```
let buffer; /* global variable

pressBtn2=(e)=> {
    buffer=/*what to write here*/;
}
```

Comment: *I need to save the prevState in the global variable "buffer"* - this is XY problem. This may result in leaks and bugs, especially if it's possible that the component is created multiple times (and this is possible in tests). Consider reasking the question with the description of the whole problem and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that is needed to recreate it. Most likely you need global state management. This is the problem that Redux solves, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
let buffer; /* global variable

pressBtn2=(e)=> {
    buffer=this.state.number
}
```

But why not just get the state directly?

```
pressBtn2=(e)=> {
    console.log(this.state.number)
}
```

Comment: I can't assign just this.state.number, it has start value. My functions change state and I need to save the previous state.

Comment: then assign in another state. I mean maintain two different state: number, prevNumber

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like follows:

```
let buffer; /* global variable

pressBtn2=(e)=> {
    buffer=this.state;
}
```